# Use a Loader with too fast request

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, request, loader

A quick question, how do you handle requests that are too fast to show correctly a loader ?

I have a submit button which show a loader until firebase respond (ajax request). But firebase is too fast (< 10ms) so my loader is showing very fast and it's not very nice.

Do you have any advices for it ? I would like to avoid setTimeout as possible...

Thanks

Comment: in the backend stop thread execution E.g. Thread.Sleep(1000) for C#.

Comment: Can't avoid using setTimeout if you don't like the current behavior

Comment: Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Why have a loader if the response is 10ms?

Comment: Sorry, it's not really a problem but i want to know what are the best practices in JS for that purpose. I put a loader because depending of the network it can be longer

Answer (score -2):

In this cases the unique way is delete the loader/spinner or set a time out.

I hope my answer are helpful

Comment: This is not an answer. Please give a few more actual answers to get the rep to comment

Comment: I don't think this is a bad answer. Because in these cases you can not use a conditional to show or not the loader and showing it too fast would be a bad user experience @mplungjan